# Java - Robot keyPress issue

Tags: java, processing, arduino, awtrobot

I'm trying to send keystrokes (like a virtual keyboard) from my Java code, but
I encounter some issues. It works perfectly on normal applications (for
example, Notepad, browsers etc.), but not on games (fullscreen or windowed
mode).

This is the stripped code I'm using:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

Robot robot;

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you already got it working...

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
```

Comment: No, I didn't .. have you tested it?

Comment: Yep, It should work with this. keyPress and keyRelease aren't static methods. Therefore you need to create a robot object.

Comment: For Notepad it works ok but inside games .. no keystrokes are being sent .. any ideas?

Comment: What game is this? What are you exactly trying to do? Control the game or type in a text field...

Comment: So... I have done a hardware interface (with Arduino and an accelerometer) that sends keystrokes .. I wanted to use it for games :) .. but it seems it is ok for normal apps only.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem myself, the problem for me was that the game was running under admin privileges, and my programm wasn't. If i  launched it via console with admin rights it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to "[Full screen mode robot keypresses simulation](http://www.coderanch.com/t/504971/GUI/java/Full-screen-mode-robot-keypresses)".

Comment: Thanks Alpine .. but it doesn't give any solution there, isn't ?

Comment: The post says that java blocks access to applications running in full screen mode. If i find a solution I will let you know.Thanks